# uncaught type error on button event listener

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to add an event listener to these buttons but I get an uncaught type error.
"uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading   draw.js:29   'addEventListener')  at draw.js:29:10.

I've tried to use the window.onload method but it still occurs what is going wrong
here is my html

```
table>
            <tr><button><i class="fa-solid fa-palette"> </i><input type="color"></button></tr>
            <tr>

                <td><button type="button" id="brush"><i class="fa-solid fa-paintbrush" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" id="fill"><i class="fa-solid fa-fill-drip" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></button></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="caligraphy"><i  class="fa-solid fa-pen-fancy" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></button></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" id="wide"><i  class="fa-solid fa-brush" style="font-size: 24px; padding:2px;"></i></button></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="shapeDraw"><i  class="fa-solid fa-circle-half-stroke" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></button></td>
                <td><button type="button" id="erase"><i  class="fa-solid fa-eraser" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and here is my js

```
let mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
let mouseButton = '',
    mouseState = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var color;
var brushWidth;
var shapeHeight;
var shapeWidth;
var shapeRad;
var customColor;

// context.lineWidth = width;
var colorSpace = document.getElementById("selectedColor");

var brushBtn = document.getElementById("brush");
var fillBtn = document.getElementById("fill");
var caliBtn = document.getElementById("caligraphy");
var wideBtn = document.getElementById("wide");
var shapeBtn = document.getElementById("shapeDraw");
var eraseBtn = document.getElementById("erase");

// tool event listeners
brushBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.lineCap = "round";
});
fillBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.fillStyle = colorSelect;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 1150, 600);
});
caliBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.lineCap = "butt";
});
```

Comment: null mean its one of the two opition `your js doesn't find the id` or `html load later than js`.  try `console.log` your btn variables and see the result

Comment: You're doing `context.lineCap = "round";` but context is not defined in your code.

Comment: they all came out as null when ran

Comment: no it is i just forgot to add it into the post

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <button>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-palette"> </i><input type="color" />
        </button>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="brush">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-paintbrush" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="fill">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-fill-drip" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="caligraphy">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-fancy" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="wide">
            <i
              class="fa-solid fa-brush"
              style="font-size: 24px; padding: 2px"
            ></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="shapeDraw">
            <i
              class="fa-solid fa-circle-half-stroke"
              style="font-size: 24px"
            ></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="erase">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-eraser" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    let mouseX = 0,
      mouseY = 0;
    let mouseButton = '',
      mouseState = false;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var canPos = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var color;
    var brushWidth;
    var shapeHeight;
    var shapeWidth;
    var shapeRad;
    var customColor;

    // context.lineWidth = width;
    var colorSpace = document.getElementById('selectedColor');

    var brushBtn = document.getElementById('brush');
    var fillBtn = document.getElementById('fill');
    var caliBtn = document.getElementById('caligraphy');
    var wideBtn = document.getElementById('wide');
    var shapeBtn = document.getElementById('shapeDraw');
    var eraseBtn = document.getElementById('erase');

    // tool event listeners
    brushBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      context.lineCap = 'round';
    });
    fillBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      context.fillStyle = colorSelect;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, 1150, 600);
    });
    caliBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      context.lineCap = 'butt';
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: already tried those articles.